# How to install IPA file in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

I have debug my flutter app on ios all is working fine i need to give IPA file to my client. IPA file is also generated but issue is now how he can install ? Because he dont have Itunes on his macbook because he have BigSur OS. And Xcode is not a good option because of size. So need to know what is the quick way to install IPA file ?

Comment: If the plug their iPhone into their Mac they can just select it in the folder list in finder.  They can drag and drop the IPA onto the phone.  You need to make sure you have included their device UDID in your ad-hoc build

Comment: You can use TestFlight to distribution the app to the tester, clients. and it's a little pain for the first time to set up but You're going to work with your client for a long time so it's worth it to setup